# Read a number of random lines from a file in Python

Tags: python

Could someone show me how I could read a random number of lines from a file in Python?

Comment: What is the range "a random number of lines"? Is the offset also random?

Comment: "A number of random lines" and "a random number of lines" are very different things.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your requirement is a bit vague, so here's another slightly different method (for inspiration if nothing else):

```
from random import random
lines = [line for line in open("/some/file") if random() >= .5]
```

Compared with the other solutions, the *number* of lines varies less (distribution around half the total number of lines) but each line is chosen with 50% probability, and only one pass through the file is required.

Comment: What is the significance of `random.random() > .5` here?

Comment: `random()` returns a random number between 0 and 1 with a uniform distribution. `random() > .5` will be true half of the time ± a normal distribution, i.e. each line is selected with 50% probability.

Comment: @PulpFiction it makes sure that each line is chosen with probability one half. The net effect is to choose a uniform element of the powerset of the set of lines in the file. This will have a random amount of randomly selected lines.

Comment: @SimonJ, unlike the other solutions, the number of lines chosen varies appropriately. There's only one subset with no lines in it and only one subset with all of the lines in it. There's no reason that they should be chosen as frequently as one of the `N!/(N-N/2)!(N/2)!` sets with `N/2` lines.

Comment: Don't know if this is the right answer for the question, but if not, it deserves it's own question! Awesome answer! :)

Comment: @aaronsterling: True, good point - this might be a more useful solution than the uniformly random number of lines.

Comment: *1UP* Simple, efficient and meets the somewhat fuzzy brief.

Comment: I recommend changing the number different than .5 because this way changing the number in the direction you need is more intuitive. For instance, first, I changed it to 0.1 to get 10 percent, but you actually have to change it to 0.9 to get 10 percent.

Answer (score 15):

To get a number of lines at random from your file you could do something like the following:

```
import random
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = random.sample(f.readlines(),5)
```

The above example returns 5 lines but you can easily change that to the number you require.  You could also change it to `randint()` to get a random number of lines in addition to a number of random lines, but you'd have to make sure the sample size isn't bigger than the number of lines in the file.  Depending on your input this might be trivial or a little more complex.

Note that the lines could appear in `lines` in a different order to which they appear in the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
import linecache
import random
import sys


# number of line to get.
NUM_LINES_GET = 5

# Get number of line in the file.
with open('file_name') as f:
    number_of_lines = len(f.readlines())

if NUM_LINES_GET > number_of_lines:
     print "are you crazy !!!!"
     sys.exit(1)

# Choose a random number of a line from the file.
for i in random.sample(range(1,  number_of_lines+1), NUM_LINES_GET)
    print linecache.getline('file_name', i)

linecache.clearcache()
```

Comment: That's not a random number of lines.

Comment: @aaronasterling: ehh ? maybe i didn't understand the question well , but he asked for a random number of lines not a random line's numbers right ???

Comment: you always return 5 lines, and 5 isn't very random :) But I agree, the question was vague.

Comment: @SimonJ: what i understand from the question is that the OP wanted __a number of random lines__ so i put number of lines to get as a var __NUM_LINES_GET__ so he can choose 3 random line of 4 or ...

Comment: true, yes - he could just change it to `NUM_LINES_GET = random.randint(1, number_of_lines)` for a truly uniformly *random number of lines*.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os,random

def getrandfromMem(filename) :
  fd = file(filename,'rb')
  l = fd.readlines()
  pos = random.randint(0,len(l))
  fd.close()
  return (pos,l[pos])

def getrandomline2(filename) :
  filesize = os.stat(filename)[6]
  if filesize < 4096 :  # Seek may not be very useful
    return getrandfromMem(filename)

  fd = file(filename,'rb')
  for _ in range(10) : # Try 10 times
    pos = random.randint(0,filesize)
    fd.seek(pos)
    fd.readline()  # Read and ignore
    line = fd.readline()
    if line != '' :
       break

  if line != '' :
    return (pos,line)
  else :
    getrandfromMem(filename)

getrandomline2("shaks12.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the offset is always at the beginning of the file:

```
import random
lines = file('/your/file').read().splitlines()
n_lines = random.randrange(len(lines))
random_lines = lines[:n_lines]
```

Note that this will read the entire file into memory.

Comment: this will only ever return the first n lines.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, one use case I found myself working with is to have a very large file with millions of rows. Often the file is zipped. I would like to have more or less a given number of random lines read, e.g. 10 000, without storing the whole file in memory.

As an example, if we use the two column file with chemical ID and SMILES from PubChem

https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/Compound/Extras/CID-SMILES.gz

we can extract roughly 10k rows out of 115_726_766 rows (at the time of writing) with

```py
import gzip
import random
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

filen = r'data/CID-SMILES.gz'
n_sample = 10_000
random.seed(1)
extracted_data = []
time_start = time.perf_counter()
with gzip.open(filen,'rb') as inf:
    n_lines_total = 0
    for inl in inf:
        n_lines_total += 1
    print(f'total number of lines: {n_lines_total}')
    inf.seek(0)
    percentage = n_sample/n_lines_total
    n_lines_selected = 0
    for i_line in tqdm(range(n_lines_total)):
        inl = inf.readline()
        if random.random() <= percentage:
            nm, smi = inl.strip().split()
            extracted_data.append((nm.decode('utf-8'), smi.decode('utf-8')))
            n_lines_selected += 1
    print(f'total number of selected lines: {n_lines_selected}')
print(f'total execution time {time.perf_counter()-time_start:.2f} sec')
```

The above takes roughly 3 min on a modest laptop. It requires two passes but it is not so bad given the size of the dataset.

The question is indeed not very clear, but perhaps this is still useful to others so I post the answer with some hesitation.