# Extracting a random line in a file without loading the file into RAM in python

Tags: python, file, svmlight

I have big svmlight files that I'm using for machine learning purpose. I'm trying to see if a sumsampling of those files would lead to good enough results.

I want to extract random lines of my files to feed them into my models but I want to load the less possible information in RAM.

I saw here ([Read a number of random lines from a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105778/read-a-number-of-random-lines-from-a-file-in-python)) that I could use linecache but all the solution end up loading everything in memory.

Could someone give me some hints? Thank you.

EDIT : forgot to say that I know the number of lines in my files beforehand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `heapq` to select *n* records based on a random number, eg:

```
import heapq
import random

SIZE = 10
with open('yourfile') as fin:
    sample = heapq.nlargest(SIZE, fin, key=lambda L: random.random())
```

This is remarkably efficient as the heapq remains fixed size, it doesn't require a pre-scan of the data and elements get swapped out as other elements get chosen instead - so at most you'll end up with `SIZE` elements in memory at once.

Comment: I forgot to say that I know the number of lines in my files, wouldn't I be able to take advantage of that?

Comment: @AdrienNK the only advantage would be if your lines were of fixed length such that you could seek directly to each record after generating *n* integers between 0 and *lines in file*... Otherwise, it offers no advantage...

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I'm still not sure exactly what is considered as a record but I'll look into that!

Comment: I thought the intention was to avoid reading the whole file. Won't that I/O time tend to dominate if the files are large enough that loading them into memory is an issue?

Comment: @holdenweb I don't know... I was working on the *but I want to load the less possible information in RAM.* and this does that (and for all we know - they're running off SSDs - so i/o time isn't necessarily such a burden)... I have mentioned that seeking is practical if lines are of a fixed length, and I just noticed that you've introduced an example of seek and find a line for where they're not. I think if performance becomes an issue, then it's down to the OP to try alternate solutions based on their specific circumstance.

Comment: Indeed, and the more alternatives to choose from the better. Having studied your solution and considered my own again I added a comment reminding people that my suggested method isn't Unicode-safe.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to do a random seek into the file then look backwards for a newline (or the start of the file) before reading a line. Here's a program that prints a random line of each of the Python programs it finds in the current directory.

```
import random
import os
import glob

for name in glob.glob("*.py"):
    mode, ino, den, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime,  mtime, ctime = os.stat(name)
    inf = open(name, "r")
    location = random.randint(0, size)
    inf.seek(location)
    while location > 0:
        char = inf.read(1)
        if char == "\n":
            break
        location -= 1
        inf.seek(location)
    line = inf.readline()
    print name, ":", line[:-1]
```

As long as the lines aren't huge this shouldn't be unduly burdensome.

Comment: This solution is fine (in my opinion, anyway) in an ASCII world, but the vagaries of multi-byte variable-length encodings mean that it cannot be considered reliable when Unicode is in use. This code is also not portable to Python 3 as presented.

Answer (score 1):

You could scan the file once, counting the number of lines. Once you know that, you can generate the random line number, re-read the file and emit that line when you see it.

Actually since you're interested in multiple lines, you should look at [Efficiently selecting a set of random elements from a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059/efficiently-selecting-a-set-of-random-elements-from-a-linked-list).

Comment: Wouldn't re-reading the file be extremely unefficient with big files? (I'm talking about >10Gb files)

Comment: ya in that case you should use the reservoir sampling technique probably